# How to Connect to sharepoint server internet site using CSOM

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, sharepoint-2013, csom

I'm trying to connect to sharepoint server(internet site) with HTTPS protocol using CSOM...I'm currently working on a Asp.Net Web API hosted in Azure that can connect to Sharepoint server(internet site) with HTTPS protocol  and fetch few details. Can it be done?

I need a method in API Controller...

It's not a Sharepoint Online site... The site URL looks similar to https://abc.xyz.com/zyx/cba

I have tried the following but it gives 403 forbidden error...

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(strSiteurl))
{
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword, strDomain);
    Web web = context.Web;
    context.Load(web, w => w.Title);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that SharePoint doesn't allow you to do a cross-domain communication with the asp sites. Instead, what you can do is create a provider hosted app for SharePoint(Hoping it is a SharePoint 2013/ Office 365 site).

Please refer to the below post which is something similar to your question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96997/is-it-possible-to-make-sharepoint-lists-accessible-cross-domain-using-rest-api